# Sink kafka topic to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

I have a project where I need to get data from JSON files using java and sink it into kafka topic, and then sink that data from the topic to mongodb.
I have found the kafka-mongodb connector, but the documentation is available only to connect using confluent plateform.
I have tried:

- Download mongo-kafka-connect-1.2.0.jar from Maven.
- Put the file in /kafka/plugins
- Added this line "plugin.path=C:\kafka\plugins" in connect-standalone.properties.
- created MongoSinkConnector.properties.

```
name=mongo-sink
topics=test
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
key.ignore=true

# Specific global MongoDB Sink Connector configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=student_kafka
collection=students
max.num.retries=3
retries.defer.timeout=5000
type.name=kafka-connect
```

and than I ran the command

`.\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\MongoSinkConnector.properties`

I got this error

```
[2020-08-09 20:18:30,329] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkConfig.createConfigDef(MongoSinkConfig.java:248)
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkConfig.<clinit>(MongoSinkConfig.java:139)
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector.config(MongoSinkConnector.java:72)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:366)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
```

EDIT:
Thanks to BogdanSucaciu for the help, I have found a solution for this.

You need to add the following jars into kafka/lib folder.

1. mongodb-driver-3.12.7.jar and mongodb-driver-core-3.12.7.jar and mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar and mongo-kafka-connect-1.0.1.jar.
2. PS: I have had some problems working with the latest mongo-kafka-connect. so I had to work with this version.

Comment: can you post the worker log at startup? it should contain something like `Loading plugin from: ...`

Comment: I can't find that line, here is a full log after I execute command:https://pastebin.pl/view/c97dbf03
Thank you again

Comment: are you sure it is the full log? It should start with something like this `Kafka Connect standalone worker initializing ...`

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure here is a screenshot. https://prnt.sc/tx6611

Comment: interesting, not even the loggers are getting loaded... Can you try using a different connector ( e.g: file-source-connector ) ? I want to determine if the problem is the connector itself or your setup ( Java / OS )

Comment: Well to do that I will be needing new configuration files which I cannot find, all I can find is for the confluent platform, I'm sorry I'm new to this, and I know only for mongodb :/

Comment: how have you got the Kafka binaries then? Have you tried the quickstart path? http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_kafkaconnect

Comment: Kafka,zookeeper and mongodb are on, I already sent message from my java program to kafka topic, I'm in the last step now, is to write from topic to mongodb

Comment: well, that's the final goal but to properly determine your issue you should try out a few things. first, try using the `file-sink-connector` to dump the data from that topic to a file. It is part of the original Kafka binaries so you shouldn't encounter any issues. Also, check if the logs are properly displayed while using that connector.

Comment: Okay I will try that, and I will tell you the output thank you for your help

Comment: Hello, the file sink is working fine, the topic writes to the file. Still not working with mongodb

Comment: I've added a list of jars that you might be missing from your setup. You can give it a try by adding those as well ( I know, manually installing stuff isn't fun )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the MongoDB driver. The MongoDB connector jar contains only the classes relevant to Kafka Connect but it still needs a [driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) to be able to connect to a MongoDB instance. You would need to download that driver and copy the jar file to the same path where you've published your connector ( `C:\kafka\plugins` ).

To keep things clean you should also create another folder inside that plugins directory ( e.g: `C:\kafka\plugins\mongodb` ) and move all the stuff relevant to this connector there.

Later Edit:

I went through an old(er) setup that I had with Kafka Connect and MongoDB Sink connector and I found the following jars:
[image]

This makes me believe that the `kafka-connect-mongdb` jar and the `mongodb-driver` won't be enough. You can give it a try though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both files are in /plugins and the error is the same (with or without them)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, these jars needs to be on the /plugins folder ?

Comment: yes, basically anything that is placed in the `plugins` folder will be available for the classloader

Comment: Hello, so I have downloaded all the files, still the same error, so I have tried to remove all the plugins from the file, and the error is not changing which means it's not loading any of the plugins

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did solve the problem.
I have got a question ? can we send a java object with JSON.serializer ? because when I do so it says unrecognized token

Comment: Happy to help! If you are referring in the context of a plain Java Producer, the answer is no. You would have to first convert your java object ( using Jackson?! ) into a JSON formatted String. Then, you can send it to the topic using the String Serializer. If you are using Spring Kafka then it would a bit easier to serialize the Java object using the JSON format.

Comment: Hello, I have tried what you have said but it didn't work, here is a link of the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429241/sinking-topic-data-from-java-producer-to-mongodb